# A rigorous treatment of the seemingly simple d.e. $x^2 y' - y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A question that I created:

> Let $y : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function of $x$ that is differentiable everywhere. Let $x^2 y' - y = 0$ be true everywhere. Find $y$.

I'm looking for a rigorous treatment of this differential equation, and the complete set of solution, i.e. how one can get from my question to the solutions rigorously, without resorting to fallacies such as dividing by zero.

My hypothesis is that the complete set of solution is the following:

$y:x \mapsto\begin{cases}
0 & x \le 0 \\
A e^{-1/x} & x > 0
\end{cases}$

where $A \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Why do you call separating variables a fallacy?

Comment: @RossMillikan [Separation of variables is a bit of a miracle that is intuitively clear except the steps are all wrong](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38916538#38916538)

Comment: @KennyLau in what way is it not just the chain rule?

Comment: @qbert it is just using the chain rule, until you suddenly include a step where you have differentials without integration sign.

Comment: If we constrain ourselves to an interval where $y$ does not vanish, then this is equivalent to $y'/y=1/x^2$. On the left you have the derivative of $\ln y(x)$, on the right you have the derivative of $-1/x$. What stops you from applying the fundamental theorem of calculus here? IOW, it's all chain rule.

Comment: Alright, I've removed the controversial phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution for some intuition (with division of zero involved):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x^2 y' - y &=& 0 \\
x^2 y' &=& y \\
\dfrac{y'}{y} &=& \dfrac1{x^2} \\
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{x^2} \ \mathrm dx \\
\ln y &=& C-\dfrac1x \\
y &=& Ae^{-1/x}
\end{array}$$

---

Substitute $x=0$ into $x^2y' - y = 0$ to see that $y=0$, so $y$ does vanish at some points, which makes a naive separation of variables unjustified.

Our first solution is the zero solution, i.e. $y=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. It does satisfy the differential equation.

If $y$ does not vanish everywhere, then $y$ must be non-zero somewhere. We will firstly prove that $y$ must be zero whenever $x<0$, then we divide into two cases, where $y(a)>0$ for some $a>0$ and where $y(a)<0$ for some $a>0$.

Now, we will proceed to prove that $y$ must vanish whenever $x<0$.

Aiming for a contradiction, assume that $y(c) \ne 0$ where $c<0$.

If $y(c)>0$, then let $s=\inf(\{x:x \le 0 \land y(x)=0\})$. Then, $y$ is positive whenever $x \in [c,s)$. From the differential equation, $y'$ is also positive, so $y$ is strictly increasing, which brings us to a contradiction as $0<y(c)<y(s)=0$. However, $s$ must exist, seeing that $y(0)=0$. This means that $c$ cannot exist.

If $y(c)<0$, a similar case can be given, with $y'$ being strictly decreasing instead of strictly increasing, and the contradiction being $0>y(c)>y(s)=0$.

We have now established that $y=0$ whenever $x<0$.

### 1. $y(a)>0$ for some $a>0$

We know, from the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, that:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x: |x - a| < \delta \implies |y(x) - y(a)| < \varepsilon$$

Now, we let $\varepsilon = y(a)$ to obtain a $\delta > 0$ such that $y([a-\delta,a+\delta]) > 0$.

Let $L=\sup(\{x:x<a \land y(x) = 0\})$. We know that the set has a supremum since it is bounded above and it is not empty ($0$ must be in that set). We even know that $0 \le L \le a-\delta$. We now prove that indeed $L$ must be $0$.

Let us consider the interval $(L,a]$, where $y$ is non-zero. Let $(L_n)$ be a sequence where $L < L_i < a$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} L_n = L$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_{y(L_i)}^{y(a)} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} &=& \displaystyle \int_{L_i}^a \dfrac1{x^2} \ \mathrm dx \\
\ln (y(a)) - \ln (y(L_i)) &=& \dfrac1{L_i}-\dfrac1a \\
y(a) &=& y(L_i) e^{1/L_i-1/a}
\end{array}$$

If $L>0$, then $y(L_i) \to 0$ anyway, but $e^{1/L_i-1/a} \to e^{1/L-1/a}$ which is finite, so $y(a)$ would be $0$, contradiction. (Note: if $L=0$, then $e^{1/L_i - 1/a}$ would go to infinity.)

Let $A$ be a constant such that $y(a) = Ae^{-1/a}$. Let $x \in (0,a]$. Then:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_{y(x)}^{Ae^{-1/a}} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} &=& \displaystyle \int_x^a \dfrac1{x^2} \ \mathrm dx \\
\ln (Ae^{-1/a}) - \ln (y(x)) &=& \dfrac1x-\dfrac1a \\
y(x) &=& A e^{-1/x}
\end{array}$$

Now, we have established that $y(x) = Ae^{-1/x}$ as long as $x \in (0,a]$.

Aiming for a contradiction, we assume that there exists $x > a$ such that $y(x) = 0$. Let $b$ be the infimum of the possible values of $x$. We note that $b \ge a+\delta$. Then, $y$ is positive whenever $x \in [a,b)$. However, from the differential equation, one can see that $y'$ would also be positive, meaning that $y$ is strictly increasing, so $y(a) < y(b)$. A contradiction arises as we would obtain $0 < y(a) < y(b) = 0$.

So, whenever $x>a$, we would have $y(x) \ne 0$. Then:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_{Ae^{-1/a}}^{x} \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} &=& \displaystyle \int_a^x \dfrac1{x^2} \ \mathrm dx \\
\ln (y(x)) - \ln (Ae^{-1/a}) &=& \dfrac1a-\dfrac1x \\
y(x) &=& A e^{-1/x}
\end{array}$$

**We have thus established that $y = Ae^{-1/x}$ whenever $x>0$.**

### 2. $y(a) < 0$ for some $a>0$

A similar case can be given.

### Conclusion

$$y = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0 \\ Ae^{-1/x} & x > 0 \end{cases}$$